# Snakemake: How to handle dynamically created files with dynamically created file names?

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I have a multifasta file `DE.faa` containing unknown number of protein sequences and having fasta headers e.g. `GB012883-PA`, `GB009065-PA`, `GB007275-PA`. I have split the multifasta file (using the rule `gather_proteins_with_no_BL62_hits`) to single fasta files with filenames: `GB012883-PA.faa`, `GB009065-PA.faa`, `GB007275-PA.faa` and now I wish to BLASTp each of them remotely.

As output from the BLASTp, I wish to have tsv files with matching file names `GB012883-PA.tsv`, `GB009065-PA.tsv`, `GB007275-PA.tsv` and search strategy files: `GB012883-PA.asn`, `GB009065-PA.asn`, `GB007275-PA.asn`.

Here's how far I have come:

```
rule gather_proteins_with_no_BL62_hits:
    input:
        all_found_prot_seqs = "DE.faa"
    output:
        directory("no_BL62_hits/"), 
        touch("fasta_expansion.done")
    script:
        "gather_proteins_with_no_BL62_hits.R"


checkpoint BLAST_missing_protein_seqs:
    input:
        flag = "fasta_expansion.done",
        seqs = "no_BL62_hits/{seq_name}.faa"
    output:
        res = "BL45_headerless/{seq_name}.tsv",
        s_t = "BL45_headerless/{seq_name}.asn"
    shell:
        r"""
        blastp -remote \
        -query {input.seqs} \
        -evalue 0.01 \
        -db nr \
        -export_search_strategy {output.s_t} \
        -word_size 2 \
        -matrix "BLOSUM45"
        -max_target_seqs 100 \
        -outfmt '6 sseqid sacc qstart' > {output.res} 2> {log}
        """


def aggregate_input(wildcards):
    with open(checkpoints.BLAST_missing_protein_seqs.get(**wildcards).output.res, 'r') as f:
        return [seq_name.rstrip() + '.tsv' for seq_name in f]


rule aggregate:
    input:
        aggregate_input
    output:
        touch("BLAST45.done")
```

However, when I run this I receive `InputFunctionException` with message: `WorkflowError: Missing wildcard values for seq_name`.

My question is:

**How do I inform Snakemake that wildcard `seq_name` refers to the sequence identifiers `GB012883-PA`, `GB009065-PA`, `GB007275-PA`  (and fix the WorkflowError)?**

Comment: I posted this same question on biostars.org with some more background details included in the ensuing discussion. You can find the thread [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/450069/#450098).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you already solved it yourself. If not, then I hope this helps. I haven't tested any of it, so you might need to patch it here and there:

```
checkpoint gather_proteins_with_no_BL62_hits:
    input:
        all_found_prot_seqs = "DE.faa"
    output:
        directory("no_BL62_hits/"), 
        touch("fasta_expansion.done")
    script:
        "gather_proteins_with_no_BL62_hits.R"


rule BLAST_missing_protein_seqs:
    input:
        flag = "fasta_expansion.done",
        seqs = "no_BL62_hits/{seq_name}.faa"
    output:
        res = "BL45_headerless/{seq_name}.tsv",
        s_t = "BL45_headerless/{seq_name}.asn"
    shell:
        r"""
        blastp -remote \
        -query {input.seqs} \
        -evalue 0.01 \
        -db nr \
        -export_search_strategy {output.s_t} \
        -word_size 2 \
        -matrix "BLOSUM45"
        -max_target_seqs 100 \
        -outfmt '6 sseqid sacc qstart' > {output.res} 2> {log}
        """


def aggregate_input(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.gather_proteins_with_no_BL62_hits.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    seq_name, = glob_wildcards(checkpoint_output + "{seq_name}.faa")
    return expand("BL45_headerless/{seq_name}.{ext}", seq_name=seq_name, ext=["tsv", "asn"])


rule aggregate:
    input:
        aggregate_input
    output:
        touch("BLAST45.done")
```

I changed which rule is the checkpoint. We can know/infer what our output must be after `gather_proteins_with_no_BL62_hits` executes, not after the execution of `BLAST_missing_protein_seqs` since that one already assumes we know what output we want. So after we execute `gather_proteins_with_no_BL62_hits` we run `aggregate_input`. Which should find all the `seq_names` you need.